# Is it possible to change privileges during installation?

Tags: install4j

For our installer application it is not necessary to install with administration privileges. But when the user decide to install to the system program folder like *C:\Program File\OurApp* then the user gets a dialog that privileges are missing and another folder has to choose/create. Now the question: is it possible to grand the previliges depending on the installation location during the installation instead before starting?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the "Request privileges" action can be added to any screen. By default it's in the "Startup" node, but you can delete it there and add it to another screen. It can have a condition expression, so it's only executed when necessary. The action starts an elevated helper process that will execute elevated actions.

---

As of install4j 6.0.4, the installation location screen will always show an error message if the selected directory is not writable. Starting with 6.0.5, you can deselect the "Check if directory is writable" property and handle writability yourself. Also added in 6.0.5 is the helper function Util::isDirectoryWritable that helps you to check if the currently available privileges allow you to write into a directory.

Comment: But how can I deactivate the popup dialog showing by install4j that the user has no permission to write to the directory? The action will be executed after this popup-dialog, isn't it?

Comment: True, that use case is not covered. Please see the update above. To get a pre-release build, please contact support@ej-technologies.com

Comment: What is the estimated release date for the new version? Maybe I can switch the version before our release.

Comment: approx. 3 months from now